# Bluetooth UI under CentOS 7 + Cinnamon

Tags: bluetooth, centos-7, cinnamon

I have a fresh CentOS 7 installation on a laptop with bluetooth transciever.  When CentOS starts I see the 'bluetooth' service started.  However, on the desktop (Cinnamon) I don't see any bluetooth icon, and there is no bluetooth applet in the menus.

I see LOTS of rpm's with 'blue' in them, and I'm not sure what to add.  I just want to pair a bluetooth headset.  Can someone tell me what RPM/package I need to add for some basic bluetooth control and monitoring from the system tray?

(I already have gnome-bluetooth and bluez packages installed)

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [blueberry](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/blueberry-1.1.9-2.el7.noarch.rpm.html). It's shipped by default with Linux Mint (cinnamon). You can install it by running in the terminal:

```
sudo yum install blueberry.noarch -y
```

Worked for me on CentOS 7 - cinnamon

Comment: Can you explain more than just giving a line of code that the OP might not understand what it's doing?